# Proguard don't offuscate assets ( how to ? )

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

On my release build I use :

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

but I have in my assets some `*.json` files that I want to exclude from offuscation because at runtime all the values from my `*.json` files are null

I use but with error some rullez :

```
-keep org.json.**
-keep json.**
```

Comment: What? No! assets are not obfuscated by proguard. There might be error in your code.

Comment: nope : if I use minifyEnabled false it works

Comment: Probably you are using some model classes, exclude them from proguard.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced same problem, but after excluding model classes from proguard, it will work.

```
-keep class com.packege.db.entity.** {*;}
```

Thanks @NabinBhandari